# Non-homogeneous, non linear Fredholm integral equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have solved integral non homogeneous, linear equations using degenerate kernel but here the the problem arise is that, the equation is non linear.
I don't know how to deal non linear Fredholm itegral equation using degenerate kernel.
The equation is 
$$u(x)=b+\lambda(\int_{0}^{1} (u(t))^2dt$$
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

$$u(x)=b+\lambda \int_{0}^{1} (u(t))^2dt$$ 
$$\int_{0}^{1} (u(t))^2dt=\text{constant} \quad\implies\quad u(x)=C= \text{constant} $$
$$C=b+\lambda \int_{0}^{1} C^2dt$$
$$C=b+\lambda C^2 \quad\to\quad C=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4\lambda b}}{2\lambda}$$
$$u(x)=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4\lambda b}}{2\lambda}$$

Comment: how can you say that $u(x)=c$ 
little confusion as to taking constant.

Comment: $b$ isn't function of $x$. Also, $\lambda$ isn't function of $x$. And $\int_{0}^{1} (u(t))^2dt$ isn't function of $x$. Thus the combination of them isn't fonction of $x$ and isn't function of anything else.